# How to return all list elements of a given length?

Tags: python, string, list, string-length

I'm trying to return words that have a specific length.

This is my code so far. `words` is a list and `size` is a positive integer.

```py
def by_size(words, size)
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == size:
```

I'm not sure how to continue. `by_size(['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dd'], 2)` should return `['bb', 'dd']`. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 24):

I would use a list comprehension:

```
def by_size(words, size):
    return [word for word in words if len(word) == size]
```

Comment: +1, list comprehensions are preferred to using sorted, filter, map and simple for loops.

Answer (score 7):

```
return filter(lambda x: len(x)==size, words)
```

for more info about the function, please see [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: simple and clean

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this:

```
In [1]: words = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dd']

In [2]: result = [item for item in words if len(item)==2]

In [3]: result
Out[3]: ['bb', 'dd']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def by_size(words,size):
    result = []
    for word in words:
        if len(word)==size:
            result.append(word)
    return result
```

Now call the function like below

```
desired_result = by_size(['a','bb','ccc','dd'],2)
```

where `desired_result` will be `['bb', 'dd']`

Comment: I think this is nice. If I want to enforce my precondition which is,"words is a list of strings. size is a positive int", is there anything I need to modify?

Comment: Yes , you can enforce your precondition with the modification like:
        **if size>-1 and if isinstance(word, str):**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use them later then returning them as a list is a good idea. Or just print them to terminal. It really depends on what you are aiming for. You can just go list (or whatever the variable name is).append within the if statement to do this.

Comment: The OP states what he's after in his question - he wants to return a list.