# How can I randomly choose a word over x number of characters from a .txt file and save it to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a list on python from a text file saved in my documents. The list contains the 1000 most commonly used words in the english dictionary, with each word on a new line in the text file.

When I tried doing:

```
wordlist = []

with open("C:\\Users\\Myname\\Documents\\words.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        wordlist.append(line)

print(wordlist)
```

The result I got was:

```
['the\n', 'of\n', 'to\n', 'and\n', 'a\n', 'in\n', 'is\n', 'it\n', 'you\n', 'that\n', 'he\n', 'was\n', 'for\n', 'on\n', 'are\n'....etc.]
```

I would like each element/word in the list to be without the quotation marks and the \n.

The second part to my question is how can I choose a random word from either that created list in python, or from the .txt file directly *(in fact I'd like to learn how to do both)* and save it to a variable?

Edit: also, how can I choose a random word **over a certain number of characters** from either that created list in python, or from the .txt file directly

I am running the latest version of python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the quotation marks since these delimit the string values. After you load the wordlists, you can do simply:

```
Python 3.6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import random
wordlist = []
with open("C:\\Users\\Myname\\Documents\\words.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        wordlist.append(line)
wordlist = list(map(lambda x : x[:-1], wordlist))
print(random.choice(wordlist))
```

Comment: Yep it works for printing a random word from the list. Is there any way though to only choose a random word over a certain number of characters/letters?

Comment: It is better to split a single post with multiple questions to several posts. This way it is easier to help. Now, your last question is duplicated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697601/python-return-elements-of-list-that-have-certain-length

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to your first question:

```
lista = ['the\n', 'of\n', 'to\n', 'and\n', 'a\n', 'in\n', 'is\n', 'it\n', 
 'you\n', 'that\n', 'he\n', 'was\n', 'for\n', 'on\n', 'are\n']

listaAux = ['\n']
trans = {ord(i): '' for i in listaAux}
lista = [j.translate(trans) for i in lista for j in i]

print(lista)
```

For the second question...  you can use this lib..

```
     import random
```

and do this:

```
lista_word = ['oi','ae','ui']
word = random.choice(lista_word)
print (word)
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing the newline character from each string you can use:

```
wordlist = []

with open("C:\\Users\\Myname\\Documents\\words.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        wordlist.append(line.strip('\n'))

print(wordlist)
```

And for choosing any random string your list you can simply use 'random'

```
import random
print(random.choice(wordList))
```